# UPDATE unknown column in on clause

Tags: mysql

column `sales_mode value` : A|B -> 1|2.

I write the sql as follows:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(t.sales_mode SEPARATOR '|')
from (select c.voc_code sales_mode
      from rv_p_ab_ass_equ a
               JOIN mysql.help_topic b
               join rv_pub_voc_transform c
                    ON b.help_topic_id < (length(a.sales_mode) - length(REPLACE(a.sales_mode, '|', '')) + 1) and
                       c.voc_code_e = substring_index(substring_index(a.sales_mode, '|', b.help_topic_id + 1), '|', -1)
      where c.voc_type_e = 'T_S_DT_TD_MODE'
        and c.system_name_e = 'WBXT_YSS_GZ45'
        and c.delete_flag = 0) t
```

This is correct.

Then I want to update the sales_mode column as follow:

```
update rv_p_ab_ass_equ p
set p.sales_mode =
        (select GROUP_CONCAT(t.sales_mode SEPARATOR '|')
         from (select c.voc_code sales_mode
               from  mysql.help_topic b
                        join rv_pub_voc_transform c
                             ON b.help_topic_id <
                                (length(p.sales_mode) - length(REPLACE(p.sales_mode, '|', '')) + 1) and
                                c.voc_code_e =
                                substring_index(substring_index(p.sales_mode, '|', b.help_topic_id + 1), '|', -1)
               where c.voc_type_e = 'T_S_DT_TD_MODE'
                 and c.system_name_e = 'WBXT_YSS_GZ45'
                 and c.delete_flag = 0) t);
```

The error: [42S22][1054] Unknown column 'p.sales_mode' in 'on clause'

After think about:
Add a layer can excute as follows:

```
update rv_p_ab_ass_equ p
set sales_mode = case
                     when p.sales_mode is null or p.sales_mode = ' ' then p.sales_mode
                     else (select n.sales_mode
                           from (select t.id, GROUP_CONCAT(t.sales_mode SEPARATOR '|') sales_mode
                                 from (select a.id, c.voc_code sales_mode
                                       from rv_p_ab_ass_equ a
                                                JOIN mysql.help_topic b
                                                join rv_pub_voc_transform c
                                                     ON b.help_topic_id <
                                                        (length(a.sales_mode) - length(REPLACE(a.sales_mode, '|', '')) + 1) and
                                                        c.voc_code_e =
                                                        substring_index(
                                                                substring_index(a.sales_mode, '|', b.help_topic_id + 1),
                                                                '|', -1)
                                       where c.voc_type_e = 'T_S_DT_TD_MODE'
                                         and c.system_name_e = '${system_name}'
                                         and c.delete_flag = 0) t
                                 group by t.id) n
                           where n.id = p.id) end
```

How can I optimize?

Comment: A correlated subquery can only refer to tables from the immediately containing query, not multiple levels up.

Comment: Do not use correlated subqueries or subqueries which refers another copy of the table from the most upper level in UPDATE query in MySQL - this is not allowed. Use multiple-table UPDATE syntax.

Comment: How fast does the `SELECT` run?  The `UPDATE`?

Comment: update ：400 thousand data，7 minutes

Answer (score 0):

First, pick either `NULL` or `' '` for that case.  Having `OR` is almost universally a slowdown.  Since a single space is problematic, especially in `VARCHARs`, I will pick `NULL` for you.

```
update rv_p_ab_ass_equ p
set sales_mode = case
                 when p.sales_mode is null or p.sales_mode = ' ' then p.sales_mode
                 ...
```

--> (2 steps)

```
-- Get rid of space:
UPDATE rv_p_ab_ass_equ p
    SET   sales_mode = NULL
    WHERE sales_mode = ' ';

UPDATE rv_p_ab_ass_equ p
    SET   sales_mode = ( SELECT ... )
    WHERE sales_mode IS NOT NULL
```

Using parts of columns is costly, especially when used in `ON` or `WHERE`.  (I am referring to substring_index, length, replace.)  I recommend you split things into pieces *before* storing into the table.  This may involve using multiple rows instead of a single row with a group_concat.

After all that, there may be more work that can be done on the second `UPDATE`.

Comment: thank you, column sales_mode in my table is not null. but, I will try your idea.

Comment: @Char1iecat - Now that I look at it again, it seems strange to be juggling the `sales_mode`.  Can you describe in words what the goal is.